# How ( Is it possible ) to ask an email server if the user is known?

Tags: networking, email, email-server

When getting a delivery status notification (Failure) this snippet is included into the message:

> Technical details of permanent failure:  Google tried to deliver your
>   message, but it was rejected by the recipient domain. We recommend
>   contacting the other email provider for further information about the
>   cause of this error. The error that the other server returned was: 550
>   550 5.1.1 User unknown (state 13).

So this means I guess that before sending the mail google made a query if the target mail server will accept it. How could I reproduce this query?

**In other words, I would like to manually query a mail server if an address exits or not.** How do I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It doesn't strike me as a very useful or productive thing to do.

Comment: @joeqwerty It's honestly a fair question for someone who doesn't have a background in MTA software. It just so happens that not having that background also means the same person won't immediately recognize that such functionality would enable spammers.

Comment: In the past there used to be a SMTP verbs `VRFY`, and `EXPN`.  These have been disabled, on almost every mail server on the Internet.  The only way to test if an account exists, is by trying to send a message.    http://cr.yp.to/smtp/vrfy.html http://www.spamresource.com/2007/01/whatever-happened-to-vrfy.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So this means I guess that before sending the mail google made a query if the target mail 
>   server will accept it

No. It means when google tried to deliver it, the server responded with user unknown.

More in details:

> 550 550 5.1.1

ANyhow...

READ THE DOCUMENTATION (smtp protocol) there actually IS a command to ask whether a mailbox exist.

Here is the bad news: most servers will NEVER answer correctly but just say yes and throw the email away. Because of Spam.